# Как разрешить/запретить индексацию главной страницы в robots.txt?

Tags: индексация

При таком описании в robots.txt, в приницпе разрешена индексация главной страницы сайта?

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /wp-content/uploads
Allow: /wp-includes/*.js
Allow: /wp-includes/*.css
Allow: /wp-content/*.js
Allow: /wp-content/*.css
Disallow: /coupon-categories/*
Disallow: /wp-admin/*
Disallow: /coupons/*
Disallow: /coupon-tags/*
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-login.php
Disallow: /wp-register.php
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: /wp-admin
Disallow: /author/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /page/
Disallow: /tag/
```

Comment: `allow: /$` чтобы разрешить и `disallow: /$` чтобы запретить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В написанных Вами запрещающих и разрешающих директориях не описано про директории которые расположены выше на раздел, в данном случае это главная страница сайта.
Получается что индексируемая если она находится в корне директории.

Вообще robots.txt предназначен для запрета индексирования, а для разрешения индексирования предназначено sitemap.xml